# How to use type with the same name in nested module signature?

Tags: ocaml, name-conflict

It is common practice to name the main type in a module as 't'. I can resolve the type names conflict between nested and container modules at a structure level as follows:

```
module Container = struct
  type t = A | B
  
  module Nested = struct
    type container_t = t
    type t = C | D

    let f = function
      | A -> C
      | B -> D
  end
end
```

Also, I can do the same trick at the signature level:

```
module type CONTAINER = sig
  type t = A | B
  
  module Nested : sig
    type container_t = t
    type t = C | D

    val f : container_t -> t
  end
end
```

'container_t' helped me to resolve the conflict, but I don't need to keep it visible.
Is there any way to hide it? How can I operate with 'CONTAINER.t' and 'Nested.t' in the Nested module signature without producing redundant types?

Comment: Your `Nested` signature needs to alias `t` _before_ introducing `type t = C | D`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Local substitutions](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/signaturesubstitution.html#ss%3Alocal-substitution) were introduced to solve this issue in OCaml 4.08. Writing,

```ml
  type container_t := t
```

will introduce a local name `container_t` for the type t which will not be part of the (external) signature of the module. For instance,

```ml
  module Nested : sig
    type container_t := t
    type t = C | D
    val f : container_t -> t
  end
  val u: Nested.container_t
```

fails with

> Error: Unbound type constructor Nested.container_t